# Using jQuery Ajax in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to learn how to use ajax within Laravel. I have a button (#btn1) and on clicking that button i want to load some response from the server to an empty div (#content).

Comment: try this one $.get(url,function(response){ $("div").html(response); })

Comment: Please add the code you are currently using to do the request. Does the console give you any errors?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#content').load(AJAX_URL);
})
```